# Linux: Use cut command to remove everything before AND after certain characters

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cut

The question is to show how many NMI's have occured. If I check "cat /proc/interrupts" it says

```
NMI:          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts
```

Now I need a one liner that returns just the 2 0's. I have done:

```
grep -P 'NMI' /proc/interrupts | cut -d ':' -f2
```

to remove the "NMI:" in the beginning but no idea how to do all the rest in the same line.

Cheers

Comment: do you want to count NMI in your file?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk` for example:

```
$ awk '/^NMI/ {print $2, $3}' /proc/interrupts
0 0
```

If you still want to use `cut`, then you firstly have to squeeze the spaces with `tr`:

```
$ grep "^NMI:" /proc/interrupts | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2,3
0 0
```

Comment: for second one, should be: `grep -P 'NMI' /proc/interrupts |tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2,3`

Comment: Yes, true point. Just that -P is not needed. Updated, thanks!

Comment: You can use `cut -w` to split by any number of whitespace (Consecutive spaces & tabs count as a single field separator)

Comment: Wasn't aware of the `-w` option to `cut`, @Carpetsmoker . In my `cut (GNU coreutils) 8.20` is not available.

Comment: @fedorqui Right, this seems to be a BSD extension ... I thought it was POSIX/universal, but apparently not. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
echo $(grep -oP 'NMI:\s+\K\d+\s+\d+' /proc/interrupts)
```

Comment: @BMW: I take advantage of _shell word splitting_ to avoid displaying not needed spaces

Answer (score 1):

For this, my weapon of choice would be `awk` since it was designed with this sort of processing in mind:

```
awk '/^NMI/{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
        if($i~/^[[:digit:]]+$/)
            printf("%10d ", $i);
    print ""
}' /proc/interrupts
```

This should work for any number of (virtual) CPUs in the event that the CPU count increases. My /proc/interrupts file has 4 numeric fields for example.